# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

That's what the compiler says when I run my react app. What I do need to do with this?

```js
request = (start,end) => {
   if(this.state.teams.length < 1){
       axios.get(`${ URL }/teams`)
       .then( response => {
           this.setState({
               teams:response.data
           })
       })
   }

    axios.get(`${ URL }/articles?_start=${start}&_end=${end}`)
    .then( response => {
        this.setState({
            items:[...this.state.items,...response.data]
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I would assume then that you dont have a value for teams.  Try checking if `this.state.teams` has a value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest to check first if the props is undefined or empty or even declared.

for example:-

```
    const card = props && props.cards && props.cards.length > 0 ?
        props.cards.map((card, i) => {
            return (
                <card >
            )
        }) : '';
```

And return your card.

Comment: This works gratefully, But do we have any generic method to use these flags. because i have 20 place where am using this flag for single component and it makes component lengthy and messy

Comment: @HidaytRahman You can do it with useEffect hook to update specific "state/flag" after getting response from the API for example.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a check to see if "teams" is undefined before trying to get the length.

```
if (value === undefined) {
    // value is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that the teams value of your component's state is initialized with an array value like this :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    state: {
      teams: [],
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're having a variable that is supposed to contain an array but is `undefined` when referencing the `length` property. Try searching for `.length` in your editor and create an empty array if it's not initialized:

```
if ((arr || []).length > 0) {
  // do something
}

// or

if (arr?.length > 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens especially in react or react native, just add a question sign e.g,

```
{title?.length>20? title?.substring(0,20)+'...':title}
```